# htaccess : redirect selected list of urls from http to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server

I want to 301 redirect lists of selected http urls (http://hostname.com/oldressource) each one leading to one new https url (http://hostname.com/newressource).

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

I have about 1000 urls to treat. Could you advice me some rules or way of doing it ?

Comment: maybe https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html?

Comment: Thx, i've read the doc but knowing the i have a huge lists of almost similars urls leading to the same page, would it be easier to just write RewriteCond ?

Comment: You said "each one leading to one new https url". Maybe you can clarify or even provide several examples?